Get-Az role assignment
help me modify this script to get all the resource groups and resources inside the subscription and there role assignment details I'm getting error doing that
$tenantId = "xxxxxxx"
$subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxx"

# Log in to Azure with tenant and subscription IDs
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $tenantId -Subscription $subscriptionId -UseDeviceAuthentication

#Role Assignment Function
Function Function-RoleAssignments(){

    Write-Host "`n> Checking IAM Role Assignments..." -ForegroundColor Green
    $Global:RoleAssignments = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
    $RoleAssignment = Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId"

    foreach($role in $RoleAssignment){
        $csvObject = New-Object PSObject
        Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Display Name" -value $role.DisplayName
        Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "SignIn Name" -value $role.SignInName
        Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Object Type" -value $role.ObjectType
        Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Object ID" -value $role.ObjectId
        Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Role" -value $role.RoleDefinitionName
        Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "RoleDefinition ID" -value $role.RoleDefinitionId
        Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Scope" -value $role.Scope
        Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Description" -value $role.Description
        Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "CanDelegate" -value $role.CanDelegate

        $Global:RoleAssignments.Add($csvObject) | Out-Null
    }
}

# Call the function to populate $Global:RoleAssignment
Function-RoleAssignments

# Export the collected quota information to a CSV file
$Global:RoleAssignments | Export-Csv -Path "RoleAssignment.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "Resource report generated and saved to RoleAssignment.csv"


You forgot to post the error message

Try below one.
$tenantId = "xxxxxxx"
$subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxx"

# Log in to Azure with tenant and subscription IDs
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $tenantId -Subscription $subscriptionId -UseDeviceAuthentication

# Function to get role assignments for a given scope
Function Get-RoleAssignments($scope) {
Write-Host "`n> Checking IAM Role Assignments for scope: $scope" -ForegroundColor Green
$roleAssignments = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$roleAssignment = Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $scope

foreach ($role in $roleAssignment) {
    $csvObject = New-Object PSObject
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Scope" -value $scope
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Display Name" -value $role.DisplayName
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "SignIn Name" -value $role.SignInName
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Object Type" -value $role.ObjectType
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Object ID" -value $role.ObjectId
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Role" -value $role.RoleDefinitionName
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "RoleDefinition ID" -value $role.RoleDefinitionId
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Description" -value $role.Description
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "CanDelegate" -value $role.CanDelegate

    $roleAssignments.Add($csvObject) | Out-Null
}
return $roleAssignments
}

# Get role assignments for the subscription
$Global:AllRoleAssignments = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$Global:AllRoleAssignments.AddRange((Get-RoleAssignments "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId"))

# Get all resource groups in the subscription
$resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup

foreach ($rg in $resourceGroups) {
# Get role assignments for the resource group
$Global:AllRoleAssignments.AddRange((Get-RoleAssignments $rg.Id))

# Get all resources in the resource group
$resources = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName
foreach ($resource in $resources) {
    # Get role assignments for the resource
    $Global:AllRoleAssignments.AddRange((Get-RoleAssignments $resource.Id))
}
}

# Export the collected role assignment information to a CSV file
$Global:AllRoleAssignments | Export-Csv -Path "RoleAssignment.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "Resource report generated and saved to RoleAssignment.csv"


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

want to get resource group name as well in Roleassignment .csv

getting below error as well :
Get-AzRoleAssignment : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Scope'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the
command again.

Give this a go,
$tenantId = "xxxxxxx"
$subscriptionId = "xxxxxxx"

# Log in to Azure with tenant and subscription IDs
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $tenantId -Subscription $subscriptionId -UseDeviceAuthentication

# Function to get role assignments for a given scope
Function Get-RoleAssignments($scope) {
Write-Host "`n> Checking IAM Role Assignments for scope: $scope" -ForegroundColor Green
$roleAssignments = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$roleAssignment = Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $scope

foreach ($role in $roleAssignment) {
    $csvObject = New-Object PSObject
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Scope" -value $scope
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Display Name" -value $role.DisplayName
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "SignIn Name" -value $role.SignInName
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Object Type" -value $role.ObjectType
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Object ID" -value $role.ObjectId
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Role" -value $role.RoleDefinitionName
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "RoleDefinition ID" -value $role.RoleDefinitionId
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Description" -value $role.Description
    Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "CanDelegate" -value $role.CanDelegate

    $roleAssignments.Add($csvObject) | Out-Null
}
return $roleAssignments
}

# Get role assignments for the subscription
$Global:AllRoleAssignments = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$Global:AllRoleAssignments.AddRange((Get-RoleAssignments "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId"))

# Get all resource groups in the subscription
$resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup

foreach ($rg in $resourceGroups) {
# Get role assignments for the resource group
$Global:AllRoleAssignments.AddRange((Get-RoleAssignments $rg.ResourceId))

# Get all resources in the resource group
$resources = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName
foreach ($resource in $resources) {
    # Get role assignments for the resource
    $Global:AllRoleAssignments.AddRange((Get-RoleAssignments $resource.Id))
}
}

# Export the collected role assignment information to a CSV file
$Global:AllRoleAssignments | Export-Csv -Path "RoleAssignment.csv" -NoTypeInformation

I believe the issue was in this line:
$Global:AllRoleAssignments.AddRange((Get-RoleAssignments $rg.Id))
It should have been:
$Global:AllRoleAssignments.AddRange((Get-RoleAssignments $rg.ResourceId))
